# Watch variable not on $scope to update a variable which is on $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a mini-view within my `ng-view` by doing something like this:

```
<div ng-include="currentPage" />
```

And then my controller looks like this

```
var currentPageIndex = 0;
var pages = ['page1.html','page2.html'];

$scope.currentPage = pages[currentPageIndex];
$scope.nextPage = function() {
    currentPageIndex++;
}
```

The problem is that angular doesn't know when `currentPageIndex` changes.

So, I've tried putting `currentPageIndex` on the `$scope`, like `$scope.currentPageIndex`, but that still doesn't let angular know that `$scope.currentPage` should change.

As I'm writing this I'm thinking that maybe this (below) will work, but is it really the best solution?

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.currentPageIndex', function(value) {
    $scope.currentPage = pages[$scope.currentPageIndex];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a function to define ng-include page (at my example, I used uppercase PAGES to refer a constant):

```
$scope.getPage = function() {
    return PAGES[$scope.page];
}
```

and your include:

```
<div ng-include="getPage(page)"></div>
```

You can see me plunkr with a functional example:

http://embed.plnkr.co/UyA0fjX5eponD7XQI8Yj/preview

Answer (score 0):

You can watch an arbitrary function:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return currentPageIndex; }, function(newValue) {
  $scope.currentPage = pages[newValue];
});
```

But this watcher may not run until Angular runs its next digest cycle. So the next thing you should figure out is what changes currentPageIndex. If the code that changes currentPageIndex runs outside Angular (for example in response to a DOM event), you can wrap it in `$scope.$apply()`:

```
$scope.$apply(function() { currentPageIndex = newValue; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
currentPageIndex++;
```

You could write a function which does this and updates the currentPage and call that instead

```
$scope.setPageIndex = function(index){
currentPageIndex = index;
$scope.currentPage = pages[index];
};

$scope.nextPage = function() {
$scope.setPageIndex(currentPageIndex++);
}
```

Or optionally if the pages and currentPageIndex variables are on scope then you could directly bind to that in your ng-include.

```
<div ng-include="pages[currentPageIndex]" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('currentPageIndex', function(value) {
    $scope.currentPage = pages[$scope.currentPageIndex];
});
```

I remove the the '$scope' then it worked for me.